# Create tables automatically from the JPA class

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

Am developing a stock management application in STS eclipse. I have created my own application context file .xml . where I have established the jdbc connection, and the database is also being automatically created from the .xml file.
I have created a new package named com.stock.mvc.entities under src/main/java. inside that package I have created the different entities that also represents the tables in the database.

upon executing; normally the database should be created, and the tables too should be created based on the entities created earlier.
but when I launch  the application; first the database is being in Mariadb instead of mysql; secondly, the tables are not being created in the database.

i need the tables to be created in order to proceed. can anyone help me?

the connection to the database in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestionStock_mvc?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value=""></property>
    </bean>
```

in persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="UP_GESTION_STOCK"
        transaction-type ="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <Properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </Properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

one entity class code:

```
@Entity
@Table (name ="article" )
public class Article implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idArticle;

    public Long getIdArticle() {
        return idArticle;
    }

    public void setIdArticle(Long idArticle) {
        this.idArticle = idArticle;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can make JPA create the tables, but I most oftenly use flyway to manage database with the code